# Android Marshmallow Text Selection Option Menu Actions

Tags: android, copy-paste

Hi I would like to add a global text selection listener which shows a sub menu for a any selected text. Android 6 allows this with the new Text Selection listener.

[image]

Is it possible to use this functionality by an external app, which then populates the sub menu?

Comment: so you would like to make your own cut-copy-paste "widget" for older phones. Maybe try to learn programming for Android platform. Add this feature to CyanogenMod repo on GitHub. I don't think that is in another way (than adding feature to existing platform) available

Comment: Oh no I am targeting Android 6. But the here described way can only be implemented by the app where it is available, but I would like make it globally available. So you install my Shortcut app, and this one listens on any text selections in every app and shows up some nice shortcuts (like translate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept is called `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` and is available in Android 6:

Define an intent filter in your Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" 
          android:label="@string/process_text_action_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then handle the intent in your activity:

```
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.process_text_main);
  CharSequence text = getIntent()
      .getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT);
  // process the text
  boolean readonly = getIntent()
  .getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY, false);
}
```

You can only define one Action per Activity.

[Source](https://medium.com/google-developers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999#.clgryxm2l)

[Example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ProcessText.java)